# Xceed Property Grid style name based on value

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, propertygrid, xceed

I want to set background of "Name2" to gray because the value is "2".

How can I achieve this?

[image]

I tried using DataTrigger with a converter on "PropertyItem" but I had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an `EditorTemplate` for the `Name2` property:

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid ...>
    <xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions>
        <xctk:EditorDefinition>
            <xctk:EditorDefinition.PropertiesDefinitions>
                <xctk:PropertyDefinition Name="Name2" />
            </xctk:EditorDefinition.PropertiesDefinitions>
            <xctk:EditorDefinition.EditorTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}">
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="2">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </xctk:EditorDefinition.EditorTemplate>
        </xctk:EditorDefinition>
    </xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions>
</xctk:PropertyGrid>
```